# rundll32.exe equivalent for 64-bit DLLs

Tags: win64, rundll32

Is there an equivalent of rundll32.exe for calling 64-bit DLLs?

Answer (score 30):

On 64-bit versions of Windows, two `rundll32.exe` programs exist:

- 64-bit: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe`
- 32-bit: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe`

If you are trying to do this from a 32-bit program, you might need to use `C:\Windows\Sysnative` or temporarily turn off WoW64 file system redirection. See the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Windows is insane, this is the most counterintuitive naming I've ever seen