# extern "C" dllexport producing strange name

Tags: c++, visual-c++

<del>I'm trying to write library with method that can be executed with `rundll32.exe`, but</del> I can't seem to force generation of proper export name:

on 32bit configuration I get `DoStuff(x,x,x,x)`
on 64bit configuration I get `DoStuff`

Why is that?

Tools: Visual Studio 2012; Windows 8

Code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DoStuff(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, lpszCmdLine, "Cookies", 0);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think they should be the same? It seems like the logical thing to expect however they're clearly different assemblies so there's no reason they have to be.

Comment: Aren't there some contradiction: "I'm trying to write 64bit configuration that can be executed with rundll32.exe."?

Comment: @ÖöTiib Welcome to windows x64 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703635/rundll32-exe-equivalent-for-64-bit-dlls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is occurring because you are using `dllexport` on a `stdcall` function.  The convention for `stdcall` on x86 is that the callee removes parameters from the stack.  Hence the parameter count is included as part of the name.  On x64 the standard calling convention is register passing hence the parameter information isn't included.